# Using System Datasource instead of User Datasource as ODBC Connectionstring

Tags: c#, odbc, connection-string, datasource

```
OdbcConnection DbConnection = null;
        try
        {
            DbConnection = new OdbcConnection(
                "Driver=SQL Anywhere 10;" +
                "Uid=user;" +
                "pwd=pass;" +
                "Dsn=<name>");
            DbConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

Now my problem is that if `<name>` is a User-Datasourcename everything is fine.
On the other hand if i use a System-Datasourcename as `<name>` it throws me an error that it can't find the Datasourcename. Any hints how i could use a System DSN?

Thanks in advance.

Two example Images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h7vh.png
http://imgur.com/5Govx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**X64 DSN** is not visible for a **X86** Application...