# DSN Util C#(Won't create)

Tags: c#, dsn

I was following this other post --> [C# DSN Util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403321/using-system-datasource-instead-of-user-datasource-as-odbc-connectionstring)

So I have the following code. (Slightly Modified)

```
OdbcConnection DbConnection = null;      
try        
{            
    DbConnection = new OdbcConnection(               
        "DataSourceName=NEWDSN;"+         
        "Driver=SQL Server;" +              
        "Description=New DSN;" +           
        "Server=<NameofServer>;");        
    DbConnection.Open();       
}         
catch (Exception e)       
{            
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);            
    Console.ReadKey();            
    System.Environment.Exit(0);        
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, I get no errors but nothing is created?  I have tried troubleshooting with the following techniques

- I am able to create one when doing it manually in the ODBC Admin tools
- When adding `"DatabaseName=blah;"`

I have tried many things in this field but am unable to produce anything.

EDIT:

Hmm, there may not be a way to create one using this code. `DBConnection.Open` seems to be my only decent option. Is it even possible to create one that will appear in the ODBC Data Source Admin?

Comment: It looks like you are just opening a connection, but not doing anything with it. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior To have the connection appear in odbc on the list. I am abe to make one manually but can't find what's wrong with the code. I will see what I can do after .open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code and example you are using is for opening a DSN that has already been created, not for actually creating them in the first place.

You probably need something more like this example

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DSNAdmin.aspx